# Angular 2 is not updating the view on HTTP get call return

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm changing a list property in my app component when an AJAX call has returned but my view is not updating accordingly.

Here is the component:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {ValuesService} from "./services/ValuesService";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [ValuesService]
})

export class AppComponent {
  values: string[];

  constructor(private valuesService: ValuesService) {
    this.values = ['1', '2'];
  }

  onClick() {
    this.valuesService.getValues().subscribe(this.onValues)
  }

  onValues(values: string[]) {
    for (let value of values) {
      console.log(value);
    }

    this.values = values // this should change the view
  }
}
```

view:

```
<button (click)="onClick()">Hit Me</button>
<div *ngFor="let value of values">
  <h3>{{value}}</h3>
</div>
```

When I click the button, I do see in the console:

```
received value1,value2,value3
app.component.ts:27 value1
app.component.ts:27 value2
app.component.ts:27 value3
```

However, the view doesn't change.

What could be causing this issue? Here are my dependencies in package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
```

EDIT:

The fix is to change:

```
this.valuesService.getValues().subscribe(this.onValues)
```

to

```
this.valuesService.getValues().subscribe(values => this.onValues(values))
```

looks like this.values = values line inside this.onValues wasn't evaluating "this" to the app, but to the function itself. It's something to do with scoping.

Comment: Can you turn this into a plunker?

Comment: @DeborahK hmm let me see if I can do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as a guess ... it could be the *this*. The normal scope for *this* is at the function level. So it may not be referencing the class property. I normally use an arrow function that gets around this issue. Something like this:

```
this.productService.getProducts()
        .subscribe(products => this.products = products,
                   error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
```

Since it is in an arrow function, the `this` here is referencing the class property.

Check this out for more information: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript

Comment: indeed, changing the code to "  onClick() {
    this.valuesService.getValues().subscribe(values => this.values = values)
  }" works. Thanks for your help. Now, how do I avoid using a lambda and instead call onValues?

Comment: ah, got it  this.valuesService.getValues().subscribe(values => this.onValues(values))